# putenv() and setenv() on Unix

Tags: c, unix

I need to get input from user and deal with variables. I need to have next features:

- `set varname = somevalue`: set the value of the environment variable named `varname` to the value specified by `somevalue`.
- `delete varname`: remove the named environment variable.
- `print varname`: prints out the current value of the named environment variable.

What I have till now is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

char * s;
char * command;
char * varName;
char * varValue;

while (s = readline("prompt> ")) {
    /* Initialise char* variables */
    command = NULL;
    varName = NULL;
    varValue = NULL;

    add_history(s); /* adds the line to the readline history buffer */

    printf("> %s\n", s); //print > sign

    int cmdNo = 1;
    int i;

    // parse through entire string
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        // check for space or = and jump over it
        while ((isspace(s[i]) || s[i] == '=') && (i < strlen(s)))
        {
            i++;           
        }
        // check if i is greater than string size 
        if (i >= strlen(s))
        {
            printf("Bad command format!\n");
            break;
        }
        // if cmdNo == 1, get the command
        if (cmdNo == 1)
        {
            int commandSize = 0;

            int index = i;

            // point index to space
            while (!isspace(s[index]))
            {
                commandSize++;
                index++;
            }

            // get command 
            command = (char*)malloc(commandSize + 1);

            int destIndex = 0;

            // copy command into command array 
            while (i<index)
            {
                command[destIndex] = s[i];
                destIndex++;
                i++;
            }

            // adding terminate character 
            command[destIndex] = '\0';
            // increase command number by 1
            cmdNo++;

        }
        // if cmdNo == 2 we deal with variable name
        else if (cmdNo == 2)
        {
            // variable name size
            int varNameSize = 0;
            int index = i;
            // point index to space
            while (!isspace(s[index]))
            {
                varNameSize++;
                index++;
            }

            // get var name 
            varName = (char*)malloc(varNameSize + 1);

            int index2 = 0;
            while (i<index)
            {
                varName[index2] = s[i];
                index2++;
                i++;
            }
            // add terminate char
            varName[index2] = '\0';
            // increment cmdNo by 1
            cmdNo++;
        }
        // if cmdNo == 3 we deal with variable value
        else if (cmdNo == 3)
        {
            int valueSize = 0;
            int index = i;
            // point index to space
            while (!isspace(s[index]) && s[index] != '\0')
            {
                valueSize++;
                index++;
            }

            // get variable value
            varValue = (char*)malloc(valueSize + 1);
            int index2 = 0;
            while (i<index)
            {
                varValue[index2] = s[i];
                index2++;
                i++;
            }
            // add terminate char
            varValue[index2] = '\0';
        }
    }
    // print command, variable name and value
    if (command != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", command);
    }
    if (varName != NULL)
    {
        printf(" %s", varName);
    }
    if (varValue != NULL)
    {
        printf(" %s\n", varValue);
    }

    /* clean up! */
    free(s);
    free(command);
    free(varName);
    free(varValue);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Obviously, I had to put somewhere `putenv()`, `setenv()` or `clearenv()`. I don't have much experience with these commands.

Also, there is some error (Segmentation fault). This is response of system
[image]

Comment: Which bit are you having trouble with?  Please [edit] your post to have a [mcve] and a clearer description of your problem.  What you have now is far from minimal - a minimal example doesn't normally read input, for example (unless the question is about reading input, in which case the example doesn't do anything else!).

Comment: 1) Don't post images of text! 2) Don't post images of text! 3) Read [ask] and follow the advice.

Comment: It's your `free` calls. You only malloc() ONE of those values, depending on the exact code path, but you `free` every single one of them. You cannot `free` a pointer which was never malloc'd in the first place.

Comment: ...or initialize all pointers to NULL first

Comment: Your question shows no correlation to `putenv()` or `setenv()`. Why the header?

Comment: copy text from the terminal and paste here would be far faster and lighter, and would make it searchable and copyable to others

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes, this example just reads input and split string like for example "set USER = john" to 3 parts. First part is set (obviously command), second part is USER (variable name) and thisrd part is value. What I am asking is how to use these 3 values to execute command putenv() or setenv() - whatever is correct.

Comment: @tofro How to use these 3 values stored in variables (command, varName and varValue) to execute command putenv() or setenv().

Comment: Your [mcve] should look something like  `#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    const char *name = "USER";
    const char *value = "John";
    setenv(name, value, 1);
}
`

Answer (score 0):

The crash is caused by your loops `while (!isspace(s[index]))` for `cmdNo` 1 and 2 -- if there is no third (or second) word on the input line, they'll run past the NUL terminator in the string and (probably) crash.  You need a check for NUL in these loops as you check in `cmdNo` 3 case.

You also have a problem if you have more than 3 words on the input line -- you'll go into an infinite loop on the 4th word.

Rather than duplicating the code for the word in `if`/`else if`/`else if` as you have done, its much better to put the words in an array.  You could even use `strtok_r` or `strsep` rather than manually parsing out the characters.